# Inserting into MySQL with python via parametrized query leads to error

Tags: python, mysql

During an insert into MySQL 5.x via python 3.x I do receive an error which I can not find the reason for. It is a simple insert:

```
self.curr.execute(""" 
    INSERT IGNORE INTO test (
        `name`
    ) 
    VALUES (%s)

    """, (                 

        item['test']                    
    )
)
```

Leading to this error:

```
Failed to save datasets. INSERT IGNORE INTO test (
                    `name`
) 
VALUES (%s) Error  1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s)' at line 4
```

Everything looks good to me, what is the problem with this insert?

Comment: What is the type of `item['test']`? If it is a string you would need to do: `item['test'],` *note*: trailing comma to make it a tuple. Parens/brackets by themselves do *not* make things tuples.

Comment: You do not need backticks on field names for the general python bindings to MySQL. Also, the tuple comment above is relevant, but I would expect that to give a different error about the incorrect number of bindings

Comment: @mechanical_meat You solved it! I can't believe there is a trailing comma needed. Could you please add an answer with a short explanation on what the reason is. This fixed my problem I was looking at for hours.

Comment: @merlin: answer added with explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's [DB-API](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15), the standard to which your database module was developed, specifies that there must be a "sequence or mapping" supplied as the parameters argument to `.execute()`.

Your argument was a string, so what was placed into the query was not understood by the database.

What is needed is to make the second (2nd) argument to `.execute()` into a sequence, and the usual sequence to use is a tuple. It's sometimes a surprise to people that a tuple is *not* formed by enclosing a value in parentheses/brackets, and that the trailing comma is necessary. Note that if you were inserting multiple values you wouldn't have run into this issue at all.

So what is needed is:

```
self.curr.execute(""" 
    INSERT IGNORE INTO test (
        `name`
    ) 
    VALUES (%s)

    """, (                 

        item['test'],
        #           ^ trailing comma!                   
    )
)
```

There is at least one database module which allows just one value to be used (i.e. not a sequence) -- in a departure from the DB-API specifications; which has thrown me off in the past.

Comment: That also explains why a similar query with two arguments did work. Thank you again for your help.